# Quest enemy stuck in an unreachable area, how do I get to him?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

[image: Mikrul Gauldurson down]

I accidentally saved my game on this and have no other recent saved game. How can I bring this sob down from there. My spells, vampire powers, arrows nothing working while he is up there.

Comment: Which platform are you playing on?

Comment: I am playing this on `PC`.

Comment: You should try using console commands to move to him or to get him to move to you. [link](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_(Skyrim))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the Unrelenting Force shout to knock him down from there. If that doesn't work and you're playing on PC, try using the console command `tcl` to noclip up to him or click him in the console and input the command `moveto player`.